# AFNetworking 2.0 POST + PHP block failure called although upload is successful

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking-2

Description of my problem is actually in question header. I'm new with web technologies, so this behaviour is for me a little striking. Why failure block is called although image upload has been completed with success? Moreover I searched an answer for my question on SoF and applied some solutions, but this error still is appearing. Please help if possible. Thank you in advance.

OBJECTIVE - C:

```
- (void)upload {

    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld%c%c.jpg", (long)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970], arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a', arc4random_uniform(26) + 'a'];
    NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]);

    NSString *URLString = @"http://myServer/myAppFolder";

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URLString]];

    AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
    [manager setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];
    [manager.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager POST:@"upload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:data name:@"uploadedfile" fileName:fileName mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"Success %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure / %@, /  %@", error, operation.responseString); //error comes from here
    }];

    [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
        NSLog(@"uploading...");
    }];
}
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
$filename="uploaded";
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'])." has been uploaded";
} else {
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Failure / Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x8a633e0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}, /  The file 1389046572lb.jpg has been uploaded;
```

Comment: Not an ios coder, but "Invalid value around character 0" for your `The file ...` message suggests that cocoa is expecting some OTHER text that you're not sending.

Comment: Why are you using `AFJSONResponseSerializer`? Your PHP is not returning JSON... Try with `[AFResponseSerializer serializer]`...

Comment: I tried to echo JSON made by json_encode in my .php file. But there was an error about garbage at end. I realised that in serializer can be problem, altough didn't know about AFHTTPResponseSerializer which is actually an answer. Thanks rokjarc for convict me! Also thanks Marc for answer :-)

Comment: You are welcome. I see that you had solved this while i was typing my answer :)

Comment: Indeed rokjarc :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in the fact that you are using `AFJSONResponseSerializer` to serialize the response of your PHP upload script.

And your PHP is not returning a JSON - thus serializer throws an error.

You could either modify PHP script so that it returns a JSON formatted result. Or you can use different type of serializer.

According to [this forum](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1387) solution would be to use `[AFResponseSerializer serializer]` - i'm not sure if it even exists. Try basic `AFHTTPResponseSerializer`.